# Mongo 4.0 replicaSet recovery SegFault

Tags: mongodb

After doing `rs.initialize()` on two repica instances (aws ubuntu 16.04) and mongo 4.0.1 I get the following SegFault which I assume happens during replicaset recovery. Is it a mongo 4.0 known issue?

Thank you in advance

Stack trace is as follows :

```
W NETWORK  [LogicalSessionCacheReap] Unable to reach primary for set rs0
F -        [rsSync-0] Invalid access at address: 0x18
F -        [rsSync-0] Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault).

 NETWORK  [LogicalSessionCacheReap] Unable to reach primary for set rs0
F -        [rsSync-0] Invalid access at address: 0x18
F -        [rsSync-0] Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault).

 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x41) [0x55cc778e0051]
 mongod(+0x237D269) [0x55cc778df269]
 mongod(+0x237D8D6) [0x55cc778df8d6]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x11390) [0x7f3e2d4b6390]
 libpthread.so.0(pthread_mutex_lock+0x4) [0x7f3e2d4aed44]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo17FreeMonController8_enqueueESt10shared_ptrINS_14FreeMonMessageEE+0x40) [0x55cc763cb6b0]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo17FreeMonController27notifyOnTransitionToPrimaryEv+0x8A) [0x55cc763cb98a]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo4repl39ReplicationCoordinatorExternalStateImpl34_shardingOnTransitionToPrimaryHookEPNS_16OperationContextE+0x2C6) [0x55cc76219a36]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo4repl39ReplicationCoordinatorExternalStateImpl21onTransitionToPrimaryEPNS_16OperationContextEb+0xF3) [0x55cc7621c1d3]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo4repl26ReplicationCoordinatorImpl19signalDrainCompleteEPNS_16OperationContextEx+0x1D9) [0x55cc7625e9d9]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo4repl8SyncTail17_oplogApplicationEPNS0_11OplogBufferEPNS0_22ReplicationCoordinatorEPNS1_14OpQueueBatcherE+0xC48) [0x55cc76306738]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo4repl8SyncTail16oplogApplicationEPNS0_11OplogBufferEPNS0_22ReplicationCoordinatorE+0x189) [0x55cc76307209]
 mongod(+0xD95756) [0x55cc762f7756]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutor11runCallbackESt10shared_ptrINS1_13CallbackStateEE+0x1B3) [0x55cc77163b43]
 mongod(+0x1C0222B) [0x55cc7716422b]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool10_doOneTaskEPSt11unique_lockISt5mutexE+0x14C) [0x55cc770d649c]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool13_consumeTasksEv+0xBC) [0x55cc770d699c]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo10ThreadPool17_workerThreadBodyEPS0_RKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE+0x96) [0x55cc770d7386]
 mongod(+0x248D600) [0x55cc779ef600]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x76BA) [0x7f3e2d4ac6ba]
 libc.so.6(clone+0x6D) [0x7f3e2d1e241d]
```

Comment: Related to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/214743/got-signal-11-segmentation-fault-mongo-db-v4-0-0?newreg=a2e49599011f48008427b848b2110cad which was closed